# Open PDF file from folder inside project in Windows Store App C#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am working on Windows Store App. I have a folder named PDF in my solution in which I have one PDF file named "sample.pdf". I want to open that PDF file using code inside my application.
I have seen many links but could not find anything useful

Help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to let the system open the file in the default viewer using LaunchFileAsync.

```
               StorageFile file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"PDF\file.pdf");
               Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
```